# Update field(property) in entity

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Have i any way update only some fields in my entity? 
For example, i want update field Name in entity man, whithout sending full entity. 
Now to change the entity I first requested it and after changing the fields, I send this entity to update.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can update the entity without updating other properties, by using the **Merge Entity** or **Insert or Merge Entity** operation.

Please see our samples for Table storage [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=storage-table). They show how to merge an entity using one of our client libraries.

Here's an excerpt from the .NET sample that may be helpful:

```
         // Create an instance of a customer entity. See the Model\CustomerEntity.cs for a description of the entity.
        CustomerEntity customer = new CustomerEntity("Harp", "Walter")
        {
            Email = "Walter@contoso.com",
            PhoneNumber = "425-555-0101"
        };

        // Demonstrate how to Update the entity by changing the phone number
        Console.WriteLine("2. Update an existing Entity using the InsertOrMerge Upsert Operation.");
        customer.PhoneNumber = "425-555-0105";
        customer = await InsertOrMergeEntityAsync(table, customer);
```

Also, see the REST API reference for the **Merge Entity** and **Insert or Merge Entity** operations:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179392.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452241.aspx

Comment: Ok, if i dont know field Email, and write into Email null. After operation "merge" in entity field Email will be null?